# Gnome Terminal Infinite loop

Tags: gnome-terminal

unknowingly I have placed

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=120x80+50+50
```

command in Gnome terminal's Edit->profile and preferences->general's run custom command.
Now when I start terminal, it keeps restarting itself, therefore I'm not able to go to settings again.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You should remove the folder `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal`, log out / in. The files are loaded on login. (and existing settings probably simply (re)written if you start gnome-terminal during the same session).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanx a lot. IT worked. now terminal is working fine. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *remove* the folder `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` (where the profiles are stored), and log out and back in. Changing the files manually during your session won't help, since they simply will be overwritten by the previous settings of the same session if you start `gnome-terminal` again.

*So:*

1. remove the folder `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal`
2. log out and back in. You will lose the possible settings changes you made, but you will have your `gnome-terminal` back.

Comment: I want to solve this problem as well as keep my settings , how can I do that? I have been searching for hours, perhaps I am not a good googler. I deliberately want to run this command on terminal startup. I put it under a script file and imported it in the bashrc file. I am using a non-login shell. Perhaps , there is problem with the script  itself. Please help me out! I am stuck.

Answer (score 4):

You can manually edit your gnome terminal settings by navigating to `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/`. Just edit the xml file with gedit and remove the offending line.

I'm unsure whether you need to edit the file directly in `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/` or the one in `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/Profile/Default`, you may need to try both.

Comment: the file in ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/  is empty

And after editing the file in ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/Profile/Default nothing is happening. the file is again reverting back after starting terminal

Comment: @SachinAgarwal Don't forget to log out and log back in after you have made the edits

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/Profile/Default`

Open `%gconf.xml` file and find the entry name "custom_command". Remove the **stringvalue** value and save the xml file.

```
<entry name="custom_command" mtime="xxxxxxxxxx" type="string">
                <stringvalue>your command here</stringvalue>
</entry>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried but when running the terminal after doing this, the file is again getting that line

Comment: @SachinAgarwal see my comment to your question.

Comment: Log out and log back in after making the edits